# location.href is not working, can't acess to link location

Tags: javascript, web, location, href

I've created a "loading page" which should be the first page that users see when they connect. It's a simple page with a central bouton that people have to click. Once they do, they access to the rest of the website. All the pages including the loading page are in the same folder. Each page of the site has its own : "XXXXX.html".

So I've created a loader.html page, and implemented a javascript function, that is here :

```js
let introBox = document.getElementById('intro');

introBox.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.location.href = "main.html";
});
```

```css
@keyframes sectionAnimation{
    0%{
        transform:scale(1);
    }
    50%{
        transform:scale(1.5);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

html {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

*,*:before,*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    & img{
        width: 50%;
    }
}

.loaderbody{
    background-image: url('../../Assets/R.png');
}

b {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.15em;
  margin-top: -1.15em;
  top: 2.3em;
  font-size: 0.67em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  opacity: 0.75;
  text-align: center;
}

b span {
  font-size: 0.785em;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#intro {
  width: 200px;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:25%;
  animation: sectionAnimation 1.5s both infinite;
  transform:scale(1);
  
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.button .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
    top: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #2acdc1;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .15s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .15s ease-out;
    transition: all .15s ease-out;
}

.button .top {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 24px 34px 22px 34px;
    border: 2px solid #04049d;
}

.button-dark .top {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.button .top .label {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #04049d;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 110%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .15s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .15s ease-out;
    transition: all .15s ease-out;
}

.button-dark .top .label {
    color: #fff;
}

.button:hover .bottom {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.button:hover .top .label {
    color: #2acdc1;
}

.button-border {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #2acdc1;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
    transition: all .25s ease-out;
}

.button:hover .top .button-border-left,.button:hover .top .button-border-right {
    height: calc(100% + 2px);
}

.button:hover .top .button-border-top,.button:hover .top .button-border-bottom {
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
}

.button-border-left {
    left: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 0;
}

.button-border-top {
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
}

.button-border-right {
    right: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 0;
}

.button-border-bottom {
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Css/main copie.css">
        <title>TP</title>
    </head>
    <body class="loaderbody">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../Js/loader.js"></script>
      <section id="intro">
        <div id="intro-content" class="center-content">
      
          <div class="center-content-inner">
      
            <div class="content-section content-section-margin">
      
              <div class="content-section-grid clearfix">
              
              <a href="#" class="button nav-link">
      
                <div class="bottom"></div>
      
                <div class="top">
      
                <div class="label">Let's go !</div>
                  
                  <div class="button-border button-border-left"></div>
                  <div class="button-border button-border-top"></div>
                  <div class="button-border button-border-right"></div>
                  <div class="button-border button-border-bottom"></div>
      
                </div>
      
                </a>
      
              </div>
      
             </div>
      
            </div>
      
           </div>
      
        </section>
      </body>
</html>
```

The element "intro" is my bouton on my loading page. However, when I click on it, I stay on the same URL. I've noticed that when I click on the box it automatically add a "#" at the end of my URL. So I assume the function is kinda working, and my click is detected.

It seems the problem is about the .location.href but I can't get it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: what is the html?

Comment: you said "All the pages including the loading page are in the same folder" but then in your code I see `document.location.href = "../Pages/main.html";`, which seems to point to a different folder. Shouldn't it be `document.location.href = "main.html";` ?

Comment: @GrafiCode My website folder at first level include many folders, including a "Page" one and a "Js" one. The code you see is my "loader.js" file, so in the JS folder. That's why i used ../ so it gets to first lvl folder. I don't know if it's clear

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean ? The website is fully local. So the URL is my file name.

Comment: What is the html of the think you are clicking? You know the code so we can make a runnable example that shows the problem.

Comment: @epascarello ty man for helping me. Here is the full code. I hope it answers your questions

Comment: this is just a 404 problem. please note, when using `location.href` path is not relative to the script folder.

Comment: Did the entire code snippet helped you ?

Comment: @GrafiCode THANK YOU so much. So location.href is relative to which folder ? HTML's folder ?

Comment: I think it's actually relative to the current url, but yes, when not using url rewrite it should be the html pages path

Comment: @GrafiCode unfortunately it's still not working. I've tried to change the href location to : "./main.html (since loader.html and main.html are in the same folder). I've tried too to put the exact URL of main.html (http://127.0.0.1:5500/Pages/main.html") and it's still not working. There is still this "#" that is added to the URL right after I click on the box. So I don't really know if it's my function that has a problem or the location.

Comment: try `let introBox = document.querySelector('#intro a.button.nav-link');`

Comment: Still not working .... Thank you again for trying to help me ! I have another question related to my case : why when I click on the  box it add a "#" to the URL ? For example : http://127.0.0.1:5500/Pages/loader.html , and when I click the URL changes to : http://127.0.0.1:5500/Pages/loader.html#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing slash `/`, your code should look like this:

```
introBox.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.location.href = "/main.html";
});
```

If you want to redirect outside your website, you have to add double slash `//`.

```
document.location.href = "//google.com";
```

**EDIT**: The actual error is on the  tag with `href="#"`, change it to `"/main.html"`.
You can remove the listener if you will, it's no longer needed.

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for your help. I've tried both but it's still not working :(

What I find weird is that even if I put the google adress, it's still not working. So I think the localisation of the link isn't really the problem. It's more about the code itself or the structure of my page, I don't know ... Sorry if I'm not clear, and thanks again for your help

Comment: Oh, i see where is the problem, there is an `<a href="#" class="button nav-link">` inside  your section with id="intro", maybe you didnt see it. Thats why its sending you to #. I will edit my response.

Comment: MAN, JUST THE BIGGEST  THANK YOU I CAN GIVE TO SOMEONE, the problem is fully solved. I don't remember why I put that #. Man thank you so much again, you made my night. TY TY TY TY <3